# What does space between types mean?

Tags: mysql, haskell

This must be something very basic. I'm not familiar with the syntax, and this is my first most difficult problem. `connection` below returns something of type `IO Connection` - but I don't understand how IO and Connection are connected / what does it mean. If you can, please tell what is the purpose of IO in this operation and how can I loose it.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Database.MySQL.Simple

-- This returns `IO Connection'
connection :: Connection
connection = do
             c <- connect defaultConnectInfo
                          { connectPassword = "password",
                            connectDatabase = "database" }
             return c
-- Possibly need to do something to `c', but don't know what

first_table :: IO String
first_table = do
              [Only i] <- query_ connection "show tables"
              return i

test_query :: IO Int
test_query = do
             [Only i] <- query_ connection "select 2 + 2"
             return i
```

However, my final goal was to find a way **to only connect to the database once**, store the connection handle somewhere and reuse it when first or second functions are called. I'm nowhere near understanding how that may be done (in Erlang, for example, I'd need to open a separate process and wait for messages requesting the connection, which is extremely cumbersome and uncomfortable - so I hope, I wouldn't need to go through anything like that...).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Database.MySQL.Simple
-- I need, instead of this function something that only connects once to the databse.
connection :: IO Connection
connection = do
             c <- connect defaultConnectInfo
                          { connectPassword = "password",
                            connectDatabase = "database" }
             return c

first_table :: IO String
first_table = do
              c <- connection
              [Only i] <- query_ c "show tables"
              return i

test_query :: IO Int
test_query = do
             c <- connection
             [Only i] <- query_ c "select 2 + 2"
             return i
```

Think of `connection` as if it was, well, let it be Java for a change:

```
public Connection getConnection() {
    if (connection == null) connection = /* JDBC does it's dirty job 
                             and creates connection handle */
    return connection;
}
```

Comment: Don't waste time trying to get the Connection somehow out of the IO monad - the IO is precisely there to force all code that uses Connection to also live in the IO Monad. Which is another way to say that with Connections, you can only do IO-ish things.

Comment: @wvxvw: The point is that while you can't get it out, you can still use `(>>=) :: IO Connection -> (Connection -> IO b) -> IO b` to take something of type `IO Connection` and a function that needs a `Connection` and put them together, as long as that function returns `IO something`. So even though you can never get anything out of `IO`, you can combine things in `IO` to make new things in `IO` until you have one big `IO` thing called `main` which gets executed by the runtime.

Comment: A C analogy would be: Could someone tell me how to get rid of the `getchar` from `int getchar()`?  I really need the `int` but have this `getchar();` in the way.  I'm not mocking - it's a common question, one I probably asked myself once upon a time.

Comment: @wvxvw - Sorry, you said here somewhere you read about monads and IO, so I assumed you know how to use things *inside* the IO monad. But +hammar has thankfully clarified.

Comment: @wvxvw: If `foo :: IO Connection` and `bar, baz :: Connection -> IO Something`, then to pass the result of `foo` into `bar`, you write `foo >>= bar`, or `do x <- foo; bar x`. The latter is just syntactic sugar for the former. If you want to feed the result of `foo` into both `bar` and `baz`, so that `foo` is only run once, you write `do x <- foo; bar x; baz x`, which is syntactic sugar for `foo >>= \x -> bar x >> baz x`.

Comment: The question has mutated far beyond the title...you should really split this into 2 or 3 questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IO` is parametrized type (called type constructor in Haskell or generic in C#/Java). In this case `String` is its type argument.

`IO String` in Haskell would be written as `IO<String>` in Java/C#/C++.

Comment: @wvxvw I don't understand what you mean by specialize (or bind) in this context.

Comment: You can use Hoogle for searching the Haskell APIs (although it doesn't cover much more than the basic libraries, AFAIK). http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/

Comment: @wvxvw - You need to use the bind method (written as `>>=`) of the `Monad` type class to use an `IO Connection`.  Specifically, if you have a function `Connection -> IO MyData`, you would use `>>=` or do-notation (which is syntactic sugar for bind) to combine the two.  You might want to read the `Monads` chapter in Learn You a Haskell (http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads).  Probably some of the preliminary sections would be useful too (esp. "Input/output" and "Functors,...").

Comment: @wvxvw The left operand to `>>=` is the IO. The right operand is a function which does something with the "contents" of the IO. So for example if you had an `IO Int` called `ioint` and you wanted to print the double of the int "inside" the IO, you'd write `ioint >>= \x -> print (2 * x)`. Or using `do` notation (which is a syntactic convenience/shortcut for using `>>=`) `do x <- ioint; print (2*x)`

Answer (score 3):

You feel like this damned `IO` is your enemy? Been there, too.

But soon you'll see that `IO` is your friend. This one may call the first enlightenment.

Seriously. Suppose you managed to smuggle a `Connection` out of the IO monad. Suppose further that there are the following "functions":

```
update :: Connection -> Table -> Key -> Column -> Value -> ()
insert :: Connection -> Table -> Key -> {(Column, Value)] -> ()
```

The problem with this becomes apparent when one thinks about the semantics of expressions like this:

```
let
    ins1 = insert conn foo "bar" [("age", 42)]
    upd1 = update conn foo "bar" "age" 43
    upd2 = update conn foo "bar" "age" 44
in (ins1, upd1, upd2)
```

First, the equal sign in definitions is meant like in mathematics. A definition is a definition and **not** a command to "execute" the right hand side of the definition.
Second, the semantic is non-strict. In this case this means that to construct the 3 tuple, we don't have to expand the definitions or evaluate them somehow. On the contrary. The truth is we must not evaluate them before their results are really really badly needed.

Here is then, one rationalization for IO-types: IO types allow you to sequentialize things in a setting where values are normally evaluated in seemingly random order or even in parallel.

Surely, you don't want to execute a handfull of SQL statements in such a way that you do not know a) if they will be run at all and b) in what order.

Hence the nice do notation, which guarantees (for the IO monad, at least) sequential execution.

(You can use >>= explicitly, but I promise, that'll be no fun.)

Comment: But nothing stops you from achieving that! `do {conn <- makeConnection   ...; result1 <- query1 conn; result2 <- query2 conn; ...}`

Comment: @wvxvw: So you're asking how to make a global connection that is shared between the functions? It's possible using `unsafePerformIO`, but I would advise against it. Passing the connection, either explicitly, or implicitly using a reader monad is a much better way of doing it than relying on global state.

Comment: @wvxvw - The queries are precisely *unconnected* with this approach. Who says they must be in the same block? They could be defined in  different modules as well. Look, just because in a Java application, say, everything is called ultimatively from main() that doesn't mean it's connected.

Comment: @wvxvw: I'm still having a tough time understanding what your end goal is here. Perhaps you could explain it [in the chat?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4064/haskell)

Answer (score 2):

The IO is there because creating the Connection involves input/output, not just pure code.  As others have said, you can't get rid of it.  But in do notation, you can make it LOOK like it's gone, and apply functions that need just a `Connection`:

```
main = do
  c <- connection
  testQuery c
```

(Assuming you make `testQuery` of type `Connection -> IO Int`)

`(<-)` is the bind operator, which will apply `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, which will work because `IO` has a `Monad` instance.

Comment: Why are you resistant to just passing the `Connection` to the functions that need it?  It seems like you're abusing the type system pretty badly, without much upside...

Comment: I'm only still giving you a hard time because I'm quite certain there's a much better solution for you.  For instance, with unsafePerformIO, I imagine you won't be able to refresh your connection when it dies?

Comment: What I've been doing lately is initializing a `Data.Pool Connection` when I start my application, and stashing that in my main `ReaderT` structure.  When something needs access to the database, I fetch the pool and do `withResource pool thingThatNeedsAConnection`.    That gives you connection pooling without unnecessary connections, and nice abstraction of the parts that don't need the DB.  You can also make the database action `(MonadIO m, IConnection d) => d -> m ()` to hide MySQL/IO details.

[Top level mutable state - HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Top_level_mutable_state)